# Broken mesh/models

Tags: 3d-view

Blender worked fine before I installed a GPU to my PC. Is it the GPU? How can I fix this? I already reinstalled to the latest version. When I try to move a cube, the orange outline only moves but not the cube and I cant click it.

[image: demo picture]

Comment: This reminds me of a scaling error I once had. I'd try to scale singular faces and see if that does the trick, recalculate normals and maybe apply transformations. Also try all suggestions from answer one, but this looks terribly familiar to me and I didn't have a problem with hardware at that point

Answer (score 0):

When you change your hardware:

### 1) Make sure it reaches the minimal requirements for your software

According to [Blender's Requirements page](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), you need a graphics card with at least 1 GB RAM and support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher.

Supported graphics cards:

- NVIDIA: GeForce 400 and newer, Quadro Tesla GPU architecture and newer, including RTX-based cards, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all GeForce and Quadro GPUs)
- AMD: GCN 1st gen and newer (list of all AMD GPUs)
- Intel: Haswell and newer (list of all Intel GPUs)
- macOS: version 10.12 or newer with supported hardware

There are also some [additional requirements for full Cycles renderer support](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

### 2) Once the hardware is upgraded, make sure their drivers are reinstalled properly and up to date.