# Why my object appears to be broken in 3d View?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I installed a new GPU, since then my mesh or object appears to be broken:

[image]

What's causing this? BTW: I already tried installing older version of Blender.

Comment: Hi and Welcome. This is no regular forum, please take your time and add all relevant details directly to your question next time rather than just posting a link to reddit. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Recommend take the tour: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, Thanks

Comment: Make sure that the GPU fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and that you have a current graphics driver installed.

Comment: How this question is different from: [Broken mesh/models](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189847/broken-mesh-models) ?